# Frequency of Gold Parcels?

Tags: snatch

Recently begun playing Snatch on IOS and in my first hour got a Golden Parcel - which I then lost because I didn't have enough gold coins to stop the other person from snatching it off me. Anyway - since then I have not found another Golden Parcel. I have been told by the person who referred the game to me that Golden Parcels contain high-quality prizes, such as real-world monies, games consoles, bikes, Now TV passes, etc, and (according to the website) holidays!

This leads to my questions:

What is the frequency of a Golden Parcel appearing?

What is the distribution of Golden Parcels like? i.e. Are they fairly common (1 per town), rare (1 per city) or impossibly rare (1 per county / country)?

Based on the combination of the two answers - how long do I have to wait in order to find another GP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this [YouTube Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SqmAJ_vNU1g&feature=youtu.be&t=6m33s) the golden parcels are rotated with the regular parcels every second until someone picks it up (at which point it becomes locked to that prize).

In terms of how often a golden parcel will be seen - that depends on how many golden parcels are in the pool of parcels. If SnatchHQ have added an extra 10,000 golden parcels to the pool of (estimating here) 3,000,000,000 regular parcels, the odds of getting a golden parcel are higher than when 9,999 users have each grabbed a golden parcel (and none of the regular parcels).

So, to answer my questions:

**What is the frequency of a Golden Parcel appearing?**

Unknown (SnatchHQ don't say how many parcels are in circulation atm, and of which how many are golden).

**What is the distribution of Golden Parcels like?**

Random - prizes in every parcel rotates every 1 second.

**How long do I have to wait in order to find another GP?**

It could be my next parcel, I may never again see another. Who knows?